Vue i18n array properties not recognised by typescript
We're working on a Quasar project that has an array of translations like this:
     "contacts": [
        {
          "title": "Health & safety",
          "person": {
            "name": "Mike"
          }
        },
        {
          "title": "IT Support",
          "person": {
            "name": "Bob"
          }
        }
      ]

In the .vue SFC we use them like this:
<q-card
  v-for="contact in $tm('contacts')"
  :key="contact"
>
  <q-card-section>
    <div>{{ $rt(contact.title) }}</div>
    <div>{{ $rt(contact.person.name) }}</div>
  </q-card-section>
</q-card>

The strings are correctly translated but typescript throws this error:

[vue-tsc] Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.

CodeSandbox example here
